# Stuck in finding an alternative to finding the hypotenuse of a right triangle (using Dickson's method)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I was trying an alternative to finding the hypotenuse of a right triangle using simple algebra and Dickson's model of a right triangle. I have a problem:

Given $r + t$ and $r + s$, how do you find $s + t$? I tried the following method:

Subtract $r + t$ from $r + s$.

Obtain $s - t$.

Here I'm stuck. How do we find $s + t$? If we find $s + t$, we will have the following:

$$(r + t + r + s + s + t) = 2r + 2s + 2t.$$

On dividing by $2$, we obtain the hypotenuse of the triangle. An alternative to this is finding $r - t$. If know $r - t$, we can find $s + t$ and follow the above procedure.

In trying more to research about it, I came across a new relation which may help you:

$s + t = √(r^2+s^2+t^2)$

To find the value (numerical) of $s+t$, can we arrive at this relation?

So the question is: Is it possible to find $s + t$ or $r - t$? If so, how, or is it impossible?

Thanks,

S Sandeep

Comment: Using $r^2+s^2=t^2$?

Comment: I didn't get you. Do you mean I have to use the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: @SandyMan, what are $r + t$ and $r + s$?  And why is $r + s + t$ the hypotenuse of the triangle?

Comment: @SandyMan, have a look at this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples#Dickson.27s_method).

Comment: L.E. Dickson had found that the sides of a right triangle can be expressed as r + t, r + s and r + s + t where r^2 = 2st. My problem is based on that. There is a documentary in Wikipedia about that.

Comment: Yes. It's the same document I mentioned.

Comment: Just knowing $r+s$ and $r+t$ is not enough to find $s+t$; there must be some more information. I gather that there is more information, as there is a right triangle involved somehow; it would be better if you were to edit the additional information into the question.

Comment: I have added more information to the question. Does it help us?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples#Dickson.27s_method).

Let $x = r + s, y = r + t, z = r + s + t$.  Then, by the Pythagorean theorem:

$$x^2 + y^2 = (r + s)^2 + (r + t)^2 = (r + s + t)^2 = z^2.$$

But:

$$(r + s)^2 + (r + t)^2 = 2{r^2} + 2rs + s^2 + 2rt + t^2$$

while

$$(r + s + t)^2 = r^2 + s^2 + t^2 + 2rs + 2st + 2rt$$

so that

$$r^2 = 2st.$$

Therefore, $r = \pm\sqrt{2st}$.

Consequently, $r - t = \pm\sqrt{2st} - t$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: But we need to know 2st right? Finding individual values for r, s and t would be more difficult than using them in equations.

Comment: It doesn't give us anything since we do not know r, s and t.

Comment: Your new piece of information, Sandy, $s+t=\sqrt{r^2+s^2+t^2}$, is exactly the same as the $r^2=2st$ in the answer. Now if you know $r+s$ and $r+t$ and you know $r^2=2st$ you should have enough information to work out $r$, $s$ and $t$. Unfortunately, it seems to lead to a 4th degree equation for $s$.

Comment: Well then, I think we'll close the question.